# python, get all unique combinations of two arrays and store them in another array

Tags: python, arrays

how can I get all unique combinations of two arrays?
Here is a simple example about my question. I have two arrays, the first one is `x=numpy.array(['var1','var2','var3'])`, the second one is `y=numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, for all variables(var) in `x`, their have same value range in `y`, so there should be `7*7*7=343` combinations.
I need to use 3 columns/2 rows array to store all possible combinations and write them in csv file. What I need is looks like:

```
        var1 var2 var3
result= 
        value value value
```

How can I do it in python? And can I store these 343 3-columns/2-rows arrays in another array ? Thanks for help!

Comment: I am failing to see where 7*7*7 is coming from.

Comment: @bereal var1 var2 var3 are all from 1 to 7, so 7^3

Comment: From what I read, `[var1, var2, var3]` is a list, so it only has three fixed values...

Comment: Why 2 columns when there are 3 variables being combined (or taken the product)? Do you really want the [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)? (for 7*7*7 values)

Comment: @ChrisCharley sorry sir, I typed it wrong. It should be 2 rows 3 columns

Answer (score 0):

Based on saying that you expect 343 combinations, you would not mind the repetition of values between the variables. In that case I suggest that you use *product* function in *itertools* package.

The code for the example you provided would be:

```py
from itertools import product

x = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

result = [list(zip(x, comb)) for comb in product(y, repeat=3)]

print(result)
print(len(result))
```

Output:

```
[[('var1', 1), ('var2', 1), ('var3', 1)], [('var1', 1), ('var2', 1), ('var3', 2)], ...]
343
```

To explain a little bit about the code, `product(y, repeat = 3)` generates all possible triplet combinations from the list "y". We are looping over all those triplets in the variable of name *comb* and we asign each value in the triplet to *var1*, *var2* and *var3* respectively using `zip(x, comb)`. Finally, we store all those combinations inside the list.

In order to generate the csv file out of it, I suggest you use *pandas* package. You would be able to turn this into a Pandas Dataframe and then save it as csv file using *df.to_csv()* function.

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your answer! Is it possible to use this way to process larger arrays for example x has 300 hundreds elements and y has 400 elements. Does it require a lot of memory spaces?

Comment: If x has 300 elements and y has 400 elements, it would provide 400^300 combinations which I don't think it would be possible to be processed and stored under this method. You might have to find another solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools.product, load to pandas and save to csv as below:

```
x=np.array(['var1','var2','var3'])
y=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

l=[i for i in itertools.product(*[y for i in range(len(x))])]

df=pd.DataFrame(l, columns=x)

df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Output in the csv file:

```
     var1  var2  var3
0       1     1     1
1       1     1     2
2       1     1     3
3       1     1     4
4       1     1     5
..    ...   ...   ...
338     7     7     3
339     7     7     4
340     7     7     5
341     7     7     6
342     7     7     7
```

Comment: Thanks for help! When x and y have large amount of elements, will the result array run out of memory of RAM?

Comment: Not only RAM. with x y having 300 and 400 elements, you cannot save the result even if you use all the hard disk memory available in the entire planet, or maybe in all planets of our galaxy. 400^300 is a really huge number